# Simple express server is not recognising route (easy)

Tags: node.js, express

New to Node.js.

Have a simple server up, but when I access localhost 3000 it loads indefinitely.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server is running on port 3000...');
```

I'm following a tutorial, and my code is the same as the video. It may be a difference in version, who knows?

The console logs "Server is running on port 3000..." when I begin the program.

Comment: Did you see any logs in the server terminal ? if yes, please post them.

Comment: Added it to the post

Comment: The `console.log` should be called asynchronously, i.e. as a callback of the `listen` method: `app.listen(3000, ()  => console.log('...'))`. Right now it's being called synchronously, immediately after the `listen` call, without actually waiting for the server to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
app.use(bodyParser.json);
```

with

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

bodyParser.json is function which you should call.

Also if you add error middleware you will see error log:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err);
})
```

**Error middleware must be added as last middleware(so it is best to put it before app.listen line)**